# Undefined References for VCPKG Dear ImGUI in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I've only started using Clion as my main environment for CPP development and I was wondering if I could get Dear ImGUI in it. Turns out I can install it through VCPKG, but it only includes the .h files no .o or anything which I suspect is giving me errors. For instance, I have been having this error for quite a while now:

```
` \[1/1\] Linking CXX executable Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.exe`  FAILED: Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.exe
`cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\\PROGRA\~1\\JetBrains\\CLion 2023.1.4\\bin\\mingw\\bin\\g++.exe" -g`CMakeFiles/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.dir/main.cpp.obj -o Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.exe -Wl,--out-`implib,libDear_Im_GUI_second_test.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  `vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/imguid.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 `-lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cmd.exe /C "cd /D `C:\\Users\\santi\\CLionProjects\\Dear_Im_GUI_second_test\\cmake-build-debug && `C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -`file C:/Users/santi/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary `C:/Users/santi/CLionProjects/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test/cmake-build-debug/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.exe `-installedDir C:/Users/santi/CLionProjects/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test/cmake-build-`debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out"" `  C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\CLion 2023.1.4\\bin\\mingw\\bin/ld.exe: `CMakeFiles/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main': `C:/Users/santi/CLionProjects/Dear_Im_GUI_second_test/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `ImGui::Text(char const\*, ...)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I'm copying the command that vcpkg outputs and that has to be added into Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Dear_Im_GUI_second_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
find_package(imgui REQUIRED)

add_executable(Dear_Im_GUI_second_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Dear_Im_GUI_second_test PRIVATE imgui::imgui)
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows how to fix it?

I tried to follow the first example of the Dear ImGUI documentation so literally generate a box with some text but this didn't work at all and it keeps giving me this error of undenifed reference.